# Possibly cloudflare preventing from streaming data (Basically sends in a single chunk)

Tags: javascript, node.js, networking, stream, cloudflare

So, this is my current implementation, you can check the following images for understanding the problem I'm facing...

```
/**
 *
 * @param {import("express").Request} req
 * @param {import("express").Response} res
 */
async function urls_post(req, res) {
    const { id: guild } = req.params;

    /** @type {{ urls?: string[] }} */
    const { urls } = req.body;

    if (!urls?.length) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Please provide URLs to crawl" });

    const app = new URLApp(guild);

    const invalidURLs = [];

    urls.forEach((u) => {
        try {
            new URL(u);
        } catch (_) {
            invalidURLs.push(u);
        }
    });

    if (invalidURLs.length)
        return res
            .status(400)
            .json({ success: false, message: "One or many of the URLs is/are not valid", invalidURLs, urls });

    await write(res, { acknowledge: true });

    await app.resetURLs().catch(console.error);

    const guildData = await GuildModel.findOne({ guild_id: guild });

    if (!guildData) return res.end(JSON.stringify({ success: false, message: "Guild is not initiated..!" }));

    guildData.urls = urls;

    await guildData.save();

    const urlProcessGenerator = app.processDocuments(...urls);

    for await (const response of urlProcessGenerator) await write(res, response);

    res.end(JSON.stringify({ success: true, urls }));
}

/**
 * @param {import("express").Response} res
 * @param {unknown} data
 */
function write(res, data) {
    if (!res.write(JSON.stringify(data) + ",")) return new Promise((r) => res.once("drain", r));
    else return new Promise((r) => process.nextTick(r));
}
```

[image: Prod]

This is what I get in production (cloudflare proxied)

[image: Dev]

This is what I want.

I'm not sure why cloudflare is waiting for the whole request to finish to send the chunk?? This is important because we use this for a probress bar, since this is being resolved as a single chunk. The progress bar basically waits for some time at 0% and shoots to 100% in a ms. Feel free to ask for further context if necessary...